# Point in polyhedron farthest from other point

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, convex-geometry

I was working on the convex optimization MOOC from Stanford and in the geometric problems chapter I was asked to solve the following quiz

> Let $P⊂R^n$ be a polyhedron described by a set of linear inequalities,
>   and a $a$ point in $R^n$. Which of the following problems are easy to
>   solve? Check all that apply. (Easy means the solution can be found by
>   solving one or a modest number of convex optimization problems.)
>
> - Find a point in $P$ that is closest to $a$ in Euclidean norm.
> - Find a point in $P$ that is closest to $a$ in $l_{\infty}$ norm.
> - Find a point in $P$ that is farthest from $a$ in Euclidean norm.
> - Find a point in $P$ that is farthest from $a$ in $l_{\infty}$ norm.

Since a polyhedron is described by a set of linear inequalities

$$ Ax \leq b $$

which are convex. And any norm (euclidean or $\infty$) is also a convex function, I believe that the four problems can be expressed as convex problems like:

$$\min_{x}/\max_{x} \quad ||x - a||_{2/ \infty} $$
$$s.t \quad Ax \leq b $$

And therefore all the options should be correct. But to my surprise, finding the point in $P$ that is farthest from $a$ in Euclidean norm was not a correct answer. 
I don quite get why

Comment: Minimizing a convex function over a convex set is easy.  Maximizing a concave function over a convex set is easy.  Maximizing a convex function over a convex set is not generally easy.

Comment: @RobPratt Ohh I understand, but Why is maximizing the infinity norm not False either? I believe that It is because it can be expressed as something like Maximize $t$ subject to $Ax \leq b$ and $|x_i - a_i| < t$ for $ i = 1, \dots, N$. Is this true?

Comment: You can maximize the infinity form by solving $2n$ easy problems (maximize $x_i-a_i$ or maximize $a_i-x_i$ subject to $Ax \le b$) and taking the largest.

Comment: @RobPratt Thanks! If you want you can formulate it as an actual answer so i can give you the approve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minimizing a convex function over a convex set is easy. Maximizing a concave function over a convex set is easy. Maximizing a convex function over a convex set is not generally easy.

You can maximize the infinity form by solving $2n$ linear programming problems (maximize $x_i−a_i$ or maximize $a_i−x_i$ subject to $Ax \le b$) and taking the largest.  If you prefer, think of these as minimizing $-x_i+a_i$ or $-a_i+x_i$ so that these are convex minimization.